# Can not get correct html content and audio files when I use Google Translate TTS API

Tags: python-2.7, python-requests, google-text-to-speech

I have some problems about the browser response header and the audio files when I use Google Translate TTS API to get the audio information.

My computer system is Windows 10 and I use Python 2.7.12

My test API url is: `http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl=en&q=student&total=1&idx=0&client=tw-ob`

My code is

```
response = requests.get(tts_url, headers=headers,timeout=2)
print response.content
print response.status_code
```

The `response.status_code` is `200`. However, the `response.content` and `response.text` are garbled.

When I write the code

```
print response.encoding
```

The result is

```
None
```

Then I open the Chrome developer tool to view the page's response headers. I do not find the Content-Encoding. The picture is

[Response Headers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SIuF5.png)

[Request Headers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e3gkG.png)

SO I do not know how to decode `response.text` and `response.content`

At the same time, I write `output.write(response.content)`. The `output` is a mp3 file. Then I open the mp3 file, but the voice is not a complete pronunciation. I think the file must have some wrong with the encoding.

So I do not know how to deal with this problem and I do not know how to convert the `response.text` or `response.content` into the correct format to play the mp3 file correctly.

Comment: My computer system is Windows 10 and I use Python 2.7.12 to code. My test API url is [link](http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl=en&q=test&total=1&idx=0&client=tw-ob)

Comment: I thought this was blocked unless you're using a hack http://stackoverflow.com/q/32053442/1256219

Answer (score 0):

the payload of the response is a binary file, therefore make sure you write the **content** as **binary** data and not as text.