# How to create mp3 from text with Google TTS?

Tags: audio, web, mp3, text-to-speech, google-text-to-speech

How to create mp3 from any text with Google TTS?

1) I try to find google.translate API, but finded only "audio to text", except "text to audio"!

2) I try to find SpeechSynthesis convert to mp3, but again find nothing!

3) I find only site "beta.soundoftext.com", they generate mp3 audio file without API interface.

So, can anyone help me, please.
I searching for any ways to convert text to SPEECH for my web-site (Dedicated Server). Thank you!

Comment: for **(1)** try researching : ["**text to speech**" API](https://www.google.co.uk/search?ei=sesBWuKhOYfFkgWpy4nQCw&q=%22google%22+%22text+to+speech%22+api) instead of _"text to audio"_. Tell us here what you've tried **specifically with** using Google TTS (show code) and what error message you get...

Answer (score 3):

I'm the creator of Sound of Text.

My site does have an API! (As of last week)

You can find the documentation for the API here: https://soundoftext.com/docs.

However, behind the scenes, I'm just using an npm library that automatically generates the Google Translate TTS link for me. Specifically, I'm using this library: https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-tts-api

I'm pretty sure every popular language has a library that does a similar thing, and I can help you find it if you tell me what language you prefer to use.

Or you can just use my API =)

Answer (score 0):

[A Python script have been created for it](http://www.hung-truong.com/blog/2013/04/26/hacking-googles-text-to-speech-api/) and the script is now available on [Github](https://github.com/hungtruong/Google-Translate-TTS).

All the input there are pretty straightforward, except for the language part where some language code might be less familiar by users, in these cases [documentation from Google is available](https://cloud.google.com/speech/docs/languages) and you can check what's the code for the language you want the engine to speak in.

Answer (score 0):

Guy Rotem wrote a js function to get a `tk` token [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40078546/4759176). I adapted it for Java:

```java
public class Hasher {
    public long shiftLeftOrRightThenSumOrXor(long num, String[] opArray) {
        long result = num;

        int current = 0;
        while (current < opArray.length)  {
            char op1 = opArray[current].charAt(1);  //  '+' | '-' ~ SUM | XOR
            char op2 = opArray[current].charAt(0);  //  '+' | '^' ~ SLL | SRL
            char xd = opArray[current].charAt(2);   //  [0-9a-f]

            assertError(op1 == '+'
                    || op1 == '-', "Invalid OP: " + op1);
            assertError(op2 == '+'
                    || op2 == '^', "Invalid OP: " + op2);
            assertError(('0' <= xd && xd <= '9')
                    || ('a' <= xd && xd <='f'), "Not an 0x? value: " + xd);

            int shiftAmount = hexCharAsNumber(xd);
            int mask = (op1 == '+') ? ((int) result) >>> shiftAmount : ((int) result) << shiftAmount;

            long subresult = (op2 == '+') ? (((int) result) + ((int) mask) & 0xffffffff)
                    : (((int) result) ^ mask);
            result = subresult;
            current++;
        }

        return result;
    }

    public void assertError(boolean cond, String e) {
        if (!cond) {
            System.err.println();
        }
    }

    public int hexCharAsNumber(char xd) {
        return (xd >= 'a') ? xd - 87 : Character.getNumericValue(xd);
    }

    public int[] transformQuery(String query) {
        int[] e = new int[1000];
        int resultSize = 1000;

        for (int f = 0, g = 0; g < query.length(); g++) {
            int l = query.charAt(g);
            if (l < 128) {
                e[f++] = l;                 //  0{l[6-0]}
            } else if (l < 2048) {
                e[f++] = l >> 6 | 0xC0;     //  110{l[10-6]}
                e[f++] = l & 0x3F | 0x80;   //  10{l[5-0]}
            } else if (0xD800 == (l & 0xFC00) &&
                    g + 1 < query.length() && 0xDC00 == (query.charAt(g + 1) & 0xFC00)) {
                //  that's pretty rare... (avoid ovf?)
                l = (1 << 16) + ((l & 0x03FF) << 10) + (query.charAt(++g) & 0x03FF);
                e[f++] = l >> 18 | 0xF0;        //  111100{l[9-8*]}
                e[f++] = l >> 12 & 0x3F | 0x80; //  10{l[7*-2]}
                e[f++] = l & 0x3F | 0x80;       //  10{(l+1)[5-0]}
            } else {
                e[f++] = l >> 12 | 0xE0;        //  1110{l[15-12]}
                e[f++] = l >> 6 & 0x3F | 0x80;  //  10{l[11-6]}
                e[f++] = l & 0x3F | 0x80;       //  10{l[5-0]}
            }

            resultSize = f;
        }

        return Arrays.copyOf(e, resultSize);
    }

    public long normalizeHash(long encondindRound2) {
        if (encondindRound2 < 0) {
            encondindRound2 = (encondindRound2 & 0x7fffffff) + 0x80000000L;
        }
        return (encondindRound2) % 1_000_000;
    }

    /*
    /   EXAMPLE:
    /
    /   INPUT: query: 'hola', windowTkk: '409837.2120040981'
    /   OUTPUT: '70528.480109'
    /
    */
    public String calcHash(String query, String windowTkk) {
        //  STEP 1: spread the the query char codes on a byte-array, 1-3 bytes per char
        int[] bytesArray = transformQuery(query);

        //  STEP 2: starting with TKK index,
        // add the array from last step one-by-one, and do 2 rounds of shift+add/xor
        String[] d = windowTkk.split("\\.");
        int tkkIndex = 0;
        try  {
            tkkIndex = Integer.valueOf(d[0]);
        }
        catch (Exception e)  {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        long tkkKey = 0;
        try  {
            tkkKey = Long.valueOf(d[1]);
        }
        catch (Exception e)  {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        int current = 0;
        long result = tkkIndex;
        while (current < bytesArray.length)  {
            result += bytesArray[current];
            long subresult = shiftLeftOrRightThenSumOrXor(result,
                    new String[] {"+-a", "^+6"});
            result = subresult;
            current++;
        }
        long encondingRound1 = result;
        //System.out.println("encodingRound1: " + encondingRound1);

        //  STEP 3: apply 3 rounds of shift+add/xor and XOR with they TKK key
        long encondingRound2 = ((int) shiftLeftOrRightThenSumOrXor(encondingRound1,
                new String[] {"+-3", "^+b", "+-f"})) ^ ((int) tkkKey);
        //System.out.println("encodingRound2: " + encondingRound2);

        //  STEP 4: Normalize to 2s complement & format
        long normalizedResult = normalizeHash(encondingRound2);
        //System.out.println("normalizedResult: " +  normalizedResult);

        return String.valueOf(normalizedResult) + "."
                + (((int) normalizedResult) ^ (tkkIndex));
    }
}
```

Once you have `tk` you need to just send a HTTP request like this (using okhttp library for sending requests):

```java
HttpUrl.Builder urlBuilder = HttpUrl.parse("https://translate.google.com/translate_tts").newBuilder();
urlBuilder.addQueryParameter("ie", "UTF-8");
urlBuilder.addQueryParameter("q", foreignWord);
urlBuilder.addQueryParameter("tl", "de");
urlBuilder.addQueryParameter("total", "1");
urlBuilder.addQueryParameter("idx", "0");
urlBuilder.addQueryParameter("textlen",
        String.valueOf(foreignWord.length()));
urlBuilder.addQueryParameter("tk", hasher.getTk(foreignWord));
urlBuilder.addQueryParameter("client", "webapp");
urlBuilder.addQueryParameter("prev", "input");

String url = urlBuilder.build().toString();
Request request = new Request.Builder()
        .url(url)
        .addHeader("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0...")
        .addHeader("Accept-Language", Locale.US.getLanguage())
        .addHeader("Referer", "https://translate.google.com/")
        .get()
        .build();

OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
Call call = client.newCall(request);
Response response = call.execute();
InputStream inputStream = response.body().byteStream();
FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(path + "/audio/" + foreignWord + ".mpga");
byte dataBuffer[] = new byte[1024];
int bytesRead;
while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(dataBuffer, 0, 1024)) != -1) {
    fileOutputStream.write(dataBuffer, 0, bytesRead);
}
```

It saves the file as `.mpga`, because that's what google returns. You can then use some other libraries to convert `.mpga` to `.mp3`.